# how to Pass command line argument ( baseURL) for selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, command-line, selenium-webdriver, command-line-arguments

Kindly help.
i have created a runnable jar for my Selenium webDriver suite. now i have to test this in multiple environment( QA , Demo box, Dev ). But my manager doesnt what it to be hard coded like below
*driver.get(baseUrl)*

As the baseURl will change according to the need. My script is given to the build team. So all they will do in the command prompt is 
*java -jar myproject-1.0.1.jar*

So my manager has asked me to send the baseUrl as a command line argument so that build team do not have to go to my script and manually change the baseUrl. They should be able to change the URL every time they run the script from the command line itself. Something like this

*java -jar myproject-1.0.1.jar "http://10.68.14.248:8080/BDA/homePage.html"*

Can somebody please guide me through this. Is it possible to send command line arguments to Selenium Web Driver *driver.get(baseUrl)*

Thanks in advance

Comment: for more info : I am using Selenium webDriver 2.45.0 version , FF v 32, TestNg framework

Comment: which build tool have you used to run tests?

Comment: I do run as  TestNG. But this is a maven project. But not using any tool to run as such

Comment: If your project contains any main java class, then you can easily pass command line parameters there. Please make it clear in question that how your jar file runs the test.

Answer (score 0):

From your question above I recon you want pass URL at runtime, means your URL changes time to time so beside hardcoded URL , you want pass at the time your automation code runs. So, let me give you 2 simple solutions.

1. You can send URL dynamically or at Run time by using javascript executor:

```java
try{
  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  js.executeScript("var pr=prompt('Enter your URL please:',''); alert(pr);");  
  Thread.sleep(15000L);
  String URL = driver.switchTo().alert().getText();
  driver.switchTo().alert().accept();

  driver.get(URL);
}catch(Throwable e)
  {
  System.out.println("failed");
}
```

Use this code in place of `driver.get();` , so that a prompt box will appear when you run your code and within 15 secs or it will throw a error(you can change the time in `Thread.Sleep`) you will give the current Valid URL and hit Enter, the navigation will go to the URL. So that you can use different URL for same set of testscripts.

2. By using Scanner Class:

```java
String url = "";
System.out.println("Enter the URL :");
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
url = s.next();
s.close();
```

By using this you can give needed URL in your Console (If you are using Eclipse).

I recommend try Javascript excutor in your code and then create a runnable jar file and just run the Jar file, you will know and it will be the better solution than commandline URL passing . Let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to supply arguments this way -Durl=foobar.com and extract them in runtime like this

String URL= System.getProperty("url")